# Fill items Horizentally in CollectionView each taking screen width in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to place items in CollectionView horizentally in one row as each item should fill the screen width. However, in the current setup it doesn't fill width of the screen. What I am looking is one item at a time in the horizental direction.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UpdateRecentItemTemplate">
            <ContentView BackgroundColor="Yellow" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <yummy:PancakeView Style="{StaticResource Pancake}" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="80" BackgroundGradientStartPoint="0,0" BackgroundGradientEndPoint="0,1">
                    <yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>
                        <yummy:DropShadow Color="{Binding BindingContext.FirstColor, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}" BlurRadius="1"></yummy:DropShadow>
                    </yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>
                    <yummy:PancakeView.BackgroundGradientStops>
                        <yummy:GradientStopCollection>
                            <yummy:GradientStop Color="{Binding BindingContext.FirstColor, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}" Offset="0" />
                            <yummy:GradientStop Color="{Binding BindingContext.SecondColor, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}" Offset="1" />
                        </yummy:GradientStopCollection>
                    </yummy:PancakeView.BackgroundGradientStops>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <Label Grid.Row="0">
                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                <FormattedString>
                                    <Span Text="{Binding ChapterID, StringFormat=' {0} '}" FontSize="Small"/>
                                    <Span Text="{Binding ArabicEnglishName, StringFormat=' {0} '}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                </FormattedString>
                            </Label.FormattedText>
                        </Label>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1">
                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                <FormattedString>
                                    <Span Text="{Binding AyaNumber, StringFormat=' Ayat No. {0}'}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                </FormattedString>
                            </Label.FormattedText>
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
</yummy:PancakeView>
            </ContentView>

[![<Grid HeightRequest="140" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Red">
                                    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Recents}"
                                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UpdateRecentItemTemplate}" x:Name="RecentView">
                                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalItemSpacing="5" Span="1" />
                                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                    </CollectionView>
                                </Grid>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to use `Carouselview` instead of `CollectionView`. With `Carouselview` we can manage to show one item at a time horizentally. So changed `CollectionView` with `Carouselview` and it worked. Additionally, I had only 4 items to show one at a time, so in this case Carouselview is more approperiate then CollectionView.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).